# 3.0 to 4.0 difference in color pass involving IOR

Tags: rendering, color, render-passes

This picture is the color pass of a render of a sphere with default pricipled BDF settings and a bar of color for flavor.
[image]
When I render it in Blender 3.6.3 (or any blender 3.x)) it is perfectly flat color, which is correct.
When I render it in 4.0.4 (4.x) I get the result on the right, which appears to have a sort of fresnel darkening on the edges, and this is incorrect, or at lease not desirable for my post process.
I found that increasing the IOR of the shader up to 2.6 or so amplifies the result:
[image]

and sheen is also making its way into the color pass, here is the same shader with sheen weight at maximum:[image]

What's going on here, and how can I fix it so that my color pass returns ONLY perfectly flat color?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151461/discussion-on-question-by-krayne-3-0-to-4-0-difference-in-color-pass-involving-i); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get perfectly flat color by outputting it using AOV passes. You will need AOV output in all your shaders(it's extra works, I know, Python scripting could help - you could ask another question for help with that, but just copy/pasting the AOV output node also speeds things up a bit) and a matching AOV pass:

[image]

[image]

It's a bit tricky to recomposite everything back, because you need to split the original color pass to this base color and what is different in it, but you can simply subtract your base color from the original color pass to get those changes and then add them back to your edited base color using ColorMix nodes:

[image]

This example would not seem so pointless if we had textures instead of solid color. Solid colors are just for the sake of simplicity here.